# MVC - Call function without change pages

Tags: forms, post, model-view-controller, actioncontroller

first of all, I have to say: I'm new in MVC and english isn't my first language, so I'll try to explain my self as best as I can.

In my index ther'are 3 *select tags*, when all 3 have a different index then 0 a partial view is loaded. the partial view is a table with bunch of *input* and *select tags*, filled by data passed from a model.
User should be able to change values in the tags and press the "save" button to commit the changes (that will be saved by a stored procedure) without reload anything.

The problem come when I try to perform this action without "change page".

I just want to connect the button "save" with the method on the controller passing the data.

***Controller Function***

```
    public void FUNCTIONCALLED(MODEL m)
    {    
        using (DBEntities data = new DBEntities ())
        {             
            data.STOREDPROCEDURE();
        }

    }
```

***partialView.cshtml***

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FUNCTIONCALLED", "CONTROLLER"))
{   
    <div class="table-head">
        <table>
            <!-- input & select stuff here -->
        </table>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Salva</button> 
    </div>
}
```

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**: if I remove form and use ajax call, i get the errore: `String too long`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input type submit send your form to the server and reload your page.

you have to use ajax method like that:

```
function Save()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("MyMethode", "MyController")",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify({ MyMethodeParam : $("#MyInputID").val() })
        }).done(function (data) {
            if (data == true)
            {
                alert("Save success");
            }
            else alert("Save error");
        }).fail(function () {
            alect("Ajax Fail");
        });
}
```

delete your form and use on click in your button like

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="save();">Save</button>
```

Comment: that was my earlier solution, but the amount of data is quite huge and change dynamically so i get the error: `generated string is too long.`

Comment: is there a way to split the content of the form using multiple ajax call?